# Is this bike good for 140 pounds?

Tags: mountain-bike, trek

[image]

Trek xcaliber 7 2014 with Alex rims

Comment: Good for what? This question is open to opinion and has too many unknown variables for anyone to provide an objective answer.

Comment: If you know the make, model and year which clearly you do then go to a search engine and search ? Took me less than 3 minutes to work out if it's a good price. Or are you just pushing for possible buyers? Flagging for closure as too broad

Comment: @T_Bacon Good for it-doesn't-matter-what, because item valuations are off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

I rode Trek for a while. I weigh 140 pounds (64 kilograms) and never had a problem with it due to my size.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the question means 140 pounds British currency, not 140 pounds weight (the asker's avatar is the crest of an English football club, for example). Any adult bike should be completely fine for somebody who weighs 140lbs.

Comment: I think this is an awesomely funny answer to a badly worded and off-topic question.  Welcome to Stackexchange !